VS 2022 installer project - The shortcut gets installed but doesn't work, it doesn't launch the associated .exe

The Target is HAcomms.exe in the Application Folder directory.  Everything looks right, but the icon that gets installed has an invalid target:

The target is just "HAcomms" which is not "HAcomms.exe" and doesn't resolve to anything at all.  So what gives?  What did I do wrong?
